# Software for Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, math-software

Background: While studying Group Theory ( Open University M208 ) I had a lot of benefit from the Mathematica Add-on package AbstractAlgebra and later from the GAP software. I am currently self-studying Galois Theory ( using Ian Stewart's Galois Theory  ).

**Question: Is there a program that calculates the Field Extensions / Galois Group for a ( simple ) polynomial ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't checked it out myself, but have you looked at ["Computing Galois Groups with Mathematica"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2872/) in the Wolfram Library Archive? From the description, it may do what you want:

> Mathematica can be used to compute and form Cayley tables of the Galois groups of polynomials in Q. In addition, Mathematica can actually define a field extension and directly produce the elements of the Galois Group.

Comment: I hoped to find a solution for my favorite software Mathematica. Although I am sure the others can do it as well ( or better, who knows ).

Answer (score 15):

Canonical answers are Sage, Pari, Magma. The first two are open source, the last one costs money but has an [online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). Type for example

`P<x>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());`

`GaloisGroup(x^6+3);`

in the online calculator and hit submit. See the online manual on how to interpret the result.

Comment: The example returns an error >> GaloisGroup(x^6+3);
               ^
User error: Identifier 'x' has not been declared or assigned

but I can have a look at the Magma manual later. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ndroock1 I am sorry. The angle brackets got swallowed up by markup. Now corrected. The point is that you need to define x as a free variable (that's what the first line is supposed to do).

Comment: In PARI/GP: `polgalois(x^6+3)`

Comment: This method is very useful.For example, (https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) 
(`polgalois(x^5+5*x+1)`) or (http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) 
(`P<x>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());GaloisGroup(x^5+5*x+1);`)

Answer (score 5):

[SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/) can calculate the Galois groups of number fields (as a group of permutations).

See [this](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/number_field/galois_group.html) page for an example.

Comment: Haven't looked at Sage for a long time because I invested a lot of time in learning Mathematica, but I suppose it's time to give it another look.